# Distribution of money following different beta-distributions

Tags: r, matlab, netlogo, finance, beta-distribution

I am trying to find a methodology (or even better, the code) to do the following in Netlogo. Any help is appreciated (I could always try to rewrite the code from R or Matlab to Netlogo):

I have $5000, which I want to distribute following different beta distributions among 10 000 actors. The maximum amount an actor may receive is $1.

Basically, I am looking for a way to generate random numbers to actors (10000 actors) in a `[0,1]` interval, following different beta distributions, where the mean of the distributed values remains equal to `0.5`. This way the purchasing power of the population (10000 actors with a mean of `0.5` is $5000) remains equal for `beta(1,1)` (uniform population) as well as, for example, `beta(4,1)` (rich population).

an example with 5 actors distributing 2,5 dollar:

```
beta(1,1) 0,5 - 0,5 - 0,5 - 0,5 - 0,5 (mean 0,5) 
beta(4,1) 0,1 - 0,2 - 0,5 - 0,7 - 1,0 (mean 0,5)
```

I've been thinking. If there is no apparent solution to this, maybe the following could work. We can write the shape of the frequency distribution of `beta(4,1)` as `y=ax^2+b` with some value for `a` and `b` (both increase exponentially).
In my case, the `integral(0-1)` of `y=ax^2+b` should be 5000. Playing around with values for `a` and `b` should give me the shape of `beta(4,1)`.

The number of actors having 0.1 should then be the the `integral(0-0.1)` of `y=ax^2+b` where `a` and `b` are parameters of the shape resembling the beta(4,1).

Is my reasoning clear enough? Could someone extend this reasoning? Is there a link between the beta distribution and a function of `a`,`b`,`x` ?

Comment: if you want the mean to stay equal to 0.5, then you should keep the two shape parameters equal; in R, `rbeta(10000,shape1=s,shape2=s)`; the larger `s` is, the more concentrated the distribution will be around 0.5

Comment: But how can we keep the total to be exactly 5000?

Comment: If you want to keep the total *exactly* 5000, you need to scale the values by their mean and multiply by 0.5 ...

Comment: but keeping shape 1 and shape 2 equal will not allow me to distribute the values with a right- or left skewed PDF. How can I distribute 5000 following a beta(4,1)?

Comment: I just made a small edit with an example how the distribution could look like for 5 actors. Now I'm looking to generate these values at random for 10000 actors

Comment: Thanks for the input and time, however, I figured out that the thing I tried to achieve is not possible.